# I am not able to avoid new trade opening once one trade is already opened

Tags: pine-script

I am new to Pine Script, I have coded a strategy that opens positions under certain conditions, the problem is that these conditions have occurred very often, so the trades open one after the other without the first being closed.
I would like to put a filter that prevents me from opening positions if I have already opened one.
The function seems trivial but for some reason I can't get it to work, after entering strategy.opentrades no trades open anymore into the charts.

Could you help me?

```
strategy.opentrades == 0

strategy.order("buy", true, 1, when = MeanPrcDev50<-LimitX and MeanPrcDev100<-LimitX and 
MeanPrcDev200<-LimitX) // buy by market if current open great then previous high
strategy.order("sell", false, 1, when = MeanPrcDev50>LimitX and MeanPrcDev100>LimitX and 
MeanPrcDev200>LimitX)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if included in the strategy line opening header that pyramiding = 1, or pyramiding is not present or specified in the header. You can also check your settings if is not included, and make sure pyramiding is set to 1 in the menu.

Comment: I've check it, pyramiding = 1.
Can you please give me the code that can avoid me to open multiple positions?

    strategy.order("buy", true, 1, when = MeanPrcDev50<-LimitX and MeanPrcDev100<-LimitX and MeanPrcDev200<-LimitX) // buy by market if current open great then previous high
strategy.order("sell", false, 1, when = MeanPrcDev50>LimitX and MeanPrcDev100>LimitX and MeanPrcDev200>LimitX)

strategy.exit("exitId", "entryId", profit = TP, stop=SL)

Answer (score 0):

```
Flat = strategy.postion_size == 0

strategy.order("buy", true, 1, when = MeanPrcDev50<-LimitX and MeanPrcDev100<-LimitX and 
MeanPrcDev200<-LimitX and Flat) // buy by market if current open great then previous high
strategy.order("sell", false, 1, when = MeanPrcDev50>LimitX and MeanPrcDev100>LimitX and 
MeanPrcDev200>LimitX)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).